# AngularJS route not working (html5 mode)

Tags: angularjs, routes

I do not understand why my routes are not working except when I remove the "/" at the beginning.

Here's my routes:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider
    .when('/', { templateUrl: 'templates/views/home.html', controller: 'HomeController' })
    .when('/about', { templateUrl: 'templates/views/about.html', controller: 'AboutController' })
    .when('/contact', { templateUrl: 'templates/views/contact.html', controller: 'ContactController' })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404' });
});
```

and my html look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/angular/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body ng-cloak ng-app="app">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="js/libs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So if I go to

```
http://example.com/angular/
```

everything goes as excepted but if i click on the "Contact" link, it will bring me to

```
http://example.com/contact
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/angular/contact
```

Any idea what is going wrong with my code?

P.S. I also have the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /angular/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [QSA,NC,L]
```

Thanks

---

Yes of course, here it is:

[image]

Let me know if you need anything else. Please note that this is the content of my "angular folder", which is at the root of my server "public_html" root.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to remove the `/` at the beginning? If that works... then...?
Angular probably doesn't intercept URLs with a leading `/` because otherwise you could get stuck within the angular app. For some sites it's totally legitimate to want to link to something other than where `<base>` points.

Comment: But how can I link to my homepage without the "/"? I tried to set my homepage route as "home" but I still want to access my homepage if I link to http://example.com/angular.

Comment: Perhaps I don't quite understand what the issue is. I might be getting confused about which `/` you're talking about. Start by closing the opened HTML elements. It's possible that by not closing the `<base>` element it's getting ignored.

Comment: The problem is not the missing closing </base> as I just try it and still not working.